# How to read Excel file with *.xlsx Extension?

Tags: java, excel

I am reading excel file**(2000000 row with 6 column)** with xlsx extension. for reading it using Java Excel API but it throw exception

```
jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Unable to recognize OLE stream
```

when try same file with xls extension it read perfectly but it reading only 65536 Row data only remaining rest of row unread.please help me how i am able to read remaining row with xlsx extension.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try use Apache POI http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html

Answer (score 1):

For reading xlsx file we use following jars,

1.dom4j-1.6.1.jar
2.org-apache-commons-codec.jar
3.poi-3.7.jar
4.poi-ooxml-3.5-FINAL.jar
5.poi-ooxml-schemas-3.11-beta2.jar
6.stax-api-1.0.1.jar
7.xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar

This is function through which you can read the the xlsx file.

```
public static void readXLSX(String path) {
    File file = new File(path);
    String value = "";
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(path));
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    Row row;
    Cell cell;

    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        row = rowIterator.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    cell = cellIterator.next();
                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                            value = "" + cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            value = "" + cell.getNumericCellValue();
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            value = "" + cell.getStringCellValue();
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                            value = " ";
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Value: "+value);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in Office '07 Microsoft changed its document format to something which is more or less a zip file that contains a large amount of XML. The Java Excel API relies on the old file format. To read something from Office '07, use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).

Answer (score -1):

1. Don't read Microsoft formats. If you want an excel document read a CSV, comma separated list.
2. Your library doesn't seem to support xlsx
3. Take a look here [Choosing an excel java api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128318/choosing-an-excel-java-api)

Comment: -1: Answers like this aren't very constructive -- I'd guess that Sam has some specific business use case where he needs to support parsing Excel files. As someone who has had to parse WML files, I completely understand why he might have that problem.

Comment: I also had to parse WML. The solution was not to parse WML. Trying to maintain compatibility with with WML is a terrible long term strategy. BUT if he wanted to do so there is #2 and #3.